# Split default test sourceset into more specific test sourcesets

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, testing, package

i'm currently setting up a new project using java, gradle and spring boot. I'm struggling to create my planned test setup. My goal is to have separate test commands and directories located IN the test package.

### What I have

I have looked into gradle sourceSets and was able to create two new sourceSets for unit and component tests. The problem I face is that I don't know if there is any way to defined the path of the sourcesets so they are inside the test directory.

```
src
-- main 
-- test
-- unit
-- component
```

### What I want

I just want the default test sourceSet to behave like a normal directory which itself contains my two testing sourceSets like this:

```
src
-- main 
-- test
---- unit
---- component
```

Is this possible and also would this be 'against the convention' or something like that?

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should be able to set paths to your source sets any way you want to. Something like this should work:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['test/unit']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['test/unit']
        }
    }

    testComponent {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['test/component']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['test/component']
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can change the names of default source sets.

Keep in mind that you will have to provide more configuration for your new source set, e.g. create new `Test` task:

```
task testComponent(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.testComponent.output
    classpath += sourceSets.main.output
}
```

And also manage its dependencies separately or extend them from already existing configuration:

```
configurations {
    testComponentCompile.extendsFrom(testCompile)
    testComponentRuntime.extendsFrom(testRuntime)
}
```

As for the convention: it's best to stick to provided defaults, but if you have the need for different structure then it's also fine. Most common case for test separation is probably when you want split unit and integration test in order to be able to run them individually.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still wondering whether there is a way to configure it somehow that `test` would execute `unit` and then `component` for example. Maybe someone has some additional insights into this.